# SVG animation working properly in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg, svg-animate

The SVG animation is working properly in chrome but not in firefox.
I am trying to start the animation 0.4 secs after the page loads. Here is the code

```
<svg width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
 <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="70">
        <animate dur="2s" attributeName="r" begin=".4" restart="whenNotActive" calcMode="spline" values="0; 100; 70; 50; 70; 95; 70; 60; 70; 75; 70; 68; 70" keySplines="0 .75 .5 1; .5 0 1 .25; 0 .25 .25 1; .5 0 1 .5; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1" keyTimes="0; 0.2564; 0.5128; 0.6154; 0.6923; 0.7436; 0.7949; 0.8462; 0.8974; 0.9231; 0.9487; 0.9744; 1" fill="freeze"></animate>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please describe exactly what's going wrong, "not working properly" is not very helpful for the reader.

Comment: It is not animating in firefox at all.

Comment: problem is with  begin=".4" check here http://jsfiddle.net/aTY4y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for begin. Try 0.4s rather than .4 and it will work. The syntax is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#ClockValueSyntax) and Firefox implements it precisely. I suggest you file a bug on Chrome that it's working incorrectly.

Here's your testcase corrected...

```
<svg width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
 <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="70">
        <animate dur="2s" attributeName="r" begin="0.4s" restart="whenNotActive" calcMode="spline" values="0; 100; 70; 50; 70; 95; 70; 60; 70; 75; 70; 68; 70" keySplines="0 .75 .5 1; .5 0 1 .25; 0 .25 .25 1; .5 0 1 .5; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1" keyTimes="0; 0.2564; 0.5128; 0.6154; 0.6923; 0.7436; 0.7949; 0.8462; 0.8974; 0.9231; 0.9487; 0.9744; 1" fill="freeze"></animate>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: That solved my problem, purely my fault. Thank you and thank you for help :)